# Organise number of days into separate sections for year, months, days, hours. Java

Tags: java, date, calendar, gregorian-calendar

is there a way of organising a number of days calculated by working out the difference between two dates, into different sections e.g. for 364 days it would be:  0 years, 11 months, 30 days, hours, minutes etc.
I thought using logical operators may work like % and / but as different months have different amounts of days and some years are leap years i'm not sure how to do it. Any help would be much appreciated. My code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CleanDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        cDate.set(2011, 0, 31, 00, 00, 00);
        Date date1 = cDate.getTime();
        Date date2 = new Date();
        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar1.setTime(date1);
        calendar2.setTime(date2);
        long milliseconds1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
        long milliseconds2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();
        long diff = milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;
        long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
        long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
        long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        System.out.println("Time in minutes: " + diffMinutes + " minutes.");
        System.out.println("Time in hours: " + diffHours + " hours.");
        System.out.println("Time in days: " + diffDays + " days.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn and use JODA time.  This isn't a good idea.

Comment: How long a time period is, say, _"Two months, eleven days"_?

Comment: I want the time period to be user defined, so the user enters a date and it outputs the years, months, days since that date. I will look into joda time. Thanks for the help

Comment: By the way, do not use a leading zero on a literal number as that is read as an [octal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could effectively use Joda Time like this:
`Interval` allows to get time interval between two dates.

```
DateTime end = new DateTime(2006, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Interval interval = new Interval(start, end);
Period period = interval.toPeriod();
System.out.println(period.getYears()+" years, "
period.getMonths()+" months, "+period.getWeeks()+" weeks, "+period.getDays()+", days");
```

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.between(          // Represent a span-of-time unattached to the timeline, on scale of days-hours-minutes-seconds.
    ZonedDateTime          // Represent a moment in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone). 
    .of( 2011 , 1 , 31 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )
    ,
    ZonedDateTime.of( … ) 
)                          // Returns a `Duration` object.
.toDaysPart()              // Or `toHoursPart`, `toMinutesPart`, `toSecondsPart`, `toNanosPart`. These return either a `long` or an `int`.
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes rather than the terrible old `Date` & `Calendar` classes. The *Joda-Time* library seen in the [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12612205/642706) is also supplanted by *java.time*.

Specifying a date and a time-of-day requires a time zone to determine an exact moment. For any given moment both the date and the time-of-day vary around the globe by zone.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
```

If you want the first moment of the day, let *java.time* determine the time-of-day for that date in that zone. A day does *not* always begin at 00:00:00.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2011 , Month.JANUARY , 31 ) ;
ZonedDateTime start = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;  // Let java.time determine the first moment of the day. Never assume 00:00:00.
```

Calculate elapsed days (actually 24-hour chunks of time), hours, minutes, and seconds using [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class. For years-months-days (calendar days, not 24-hour chunks of time), use [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class.

```
ZonedDateTime stop = … ;
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop ) ;
```

Generate a `String` object with text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format.

```
String output = d.toString() ;  // Generate standard ISO 8601 text.
```

> PT2H3M42.725S

Extract the various pieces.

```
long days = d.toDaysPart() ;       // 24-hour chunks of time, *not* calendar days.
int hours = d.toHoursPart() ;
int minutes = d.toMinutesPart() ;
int seconds = d.toSecondsPart() ;
int nanos = d.toNanosPart() ;      // Fractional second as a count of nanoseconds, from 0 to 999,999,999.
```

## Years-months-days versus days-hours-minutes-seconds

If you think about it, trying to represent a span-of-time in terms of years-months-days-hours-minutes-seconds rarely makes sense. There are tricky issues involved such as calendar days versus 24-hour chunks of time, and the fact that days vary in length such as 23, 24, 25 or other number of hours long.

But if you really insist on this approach, add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project to access the [`PeriodDuration`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html) class. This class attempts to combine the two concepts.

> An amount of time in the ISO-8601 calendar system that combines a period and a duration.
>
> This class models a quantity or amount of time in terms of a Period and Duration. A period is a date-based amount of time, consisting of years, months and days. A duration is a time-based amount of time, consisting of seconds and nanoseconds. See the Period and Duration classes for more details.
>
> The days in a period take account of daylight saving changes (23 or 25 hour days). When performing calculations, the period is added first, then the duration.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).